# something about linux pipe and string handle

Tags: linux

I'm new to linux.I ask two questions,here are the commands:

```
echo 'fs4df2sf23d4f' | sed 's/2/4/g'
```

this only change 2 to 4,and I want to make the result as when number then number*2,how to write the expression?

```
cat test.txt | grep 123 > test.txt
```

when then I use `cat a.txt`,the result shows nothing,it happens when `cat A | grep * > A`

if `cat A | grep * > B;cat B > A`,the result is true,but if there is way that I don't use B?

Comment: In the second part. do you use `cat test.txt` or `cat a.txt` ?

Comment: unclear what exactly the question is here.  You've shown us what you are doing - which is good - but not what your expected input and output is.  Please give us more to work with.  Thanks!

Comment: question 1 : I want to replace the number by the previous number multiply by 2,or more exactly,I want to implement `sed "s/a/【expression with a】/g"`

Comment: question 2: when cat a file A and redirect it into A file itself,such like `cat A |grep "123" > A`,the A file while be an empty file,I can't understand why ,and I thinked a way by redirecting the result to B,and then second shell redirect to A,by it seems not good,is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not good at english,help me ,thanks~